# Mongo query $out not working in version 4.0.4

Tags: mongodb

i have a query to convert array of string into array of object in different collection. its work fine for below 4 versions but not working with 4.0.4 db version

```
db.users.aggregate([
      { "$addFields": {
        "profile.carIds": {
         "$map": {
          "input": "$profile.carIds",
          "as": "card",
          "in": {
          "id": "$$card"
          }
         }
        }
      }},
     { "$out": "users_new" }
   ])
```

`
I need solution for version 4.0.4

Comment: what error are you getting? found this in mongo issues https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-36070

Comment: This is what i am receiving while executing above query
{"message" : "unrecognized field 'retryWrites'", "operationTime" : "Timestamp(1545662560, 10)", "ok" : 0, "code" : 9, "codeName" : "FailedToParse", "$clusterTime" : { "clusterTime" : "Timestamp(1545662560, 10)", "signature" : { "hash" : "ABXIDDVTJpEWse6OaMfLtvwnNk8=", "keyId" : "6618531602269995009" } }, "name" : "MongoError" }

Comment: What specific client driver or application version are you using? If using the `mongo` shell, please edit your question to include the output of `version()` and `db.version()`.

Comment: Done. I am using mysqlbooster and mongoose both returns above error. One more thing above query is working fine with below 4 db version